# MLFlow: cannot specify base image for "mlflow models build-docker"

Tags: docker, mlflow

With mlflow models build-docker, it always creates the image from a hardcoded definition (the _DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE string in mlflow.models.docker_utils.py), which is a pretty 'heavy' image of about 3GB.
It here a way to overrule this build-in dockerfile definition so you can use more lightweight docker images?
Furthermore, it looks like the docker image is serving the model via java which pulls in a lot of additional dependencies. Why can't the default just use the python-func concept, just like mlflow serve on a local system?

Thanks, and by the way, I really like mlflow!

**Update Sept 27, 2021: (in response to comment)**

How to reproduce: (from CLI)

```
    mlflow models build-docker -m {model uri) -n {docker name}
```

The docker file is always based on what has been hardcoded in

```
    mlflow.models.docker_utils.py
```

in a string called

```
    _DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE
```

this string is used in the function

```
 _build_image(....)   (line 80)
```

where in line 103 it is actually used for creating a local docker file based on this string

```
        with open(os.path.join(cwd, "Dockerfile"), "w") as f:
            f.write(
                _DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE.format(
```

I would have expected that it would take a user-specified Dockerfile as input instead of the hardcoded _DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the description and hope it is clear like this if you open the file mlflow/models/docker_utils.py